Movie about an orphaned boy whose father is transitioning
I am looking for a movie, which as far as I recall is not American, in which the plot starts as follows:
A young boy is living with his mother in a rural or small town setting. The mother dies. The boy's paternal grandfather, who lives in the big city, comes to get him. It is then revealed that the boy's father is in the process of transitioning from male to female.
I think the movie has only been released recently. 
The boy is young, about 10. The father works as a female performer at a night club. 
I remember two scenes. In one, the boy asks his father, who is on his way to the operation, to stay with him, saying that he can be a woman if he wants. 
In the final scene, as the boy and his grandfather are leaving the big city, the father promises to come and take the son after the operation, in the summer.

In Transamerica some plot elements are identical.

Hi. Do you remember the year\decade? Any particular scenes? The actors or what they looked like?
